# Cannot GET with Angular 2 CLI build

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-cli

After building a project with Angular CLI, I keep getting `404:Cannot GET` with my inline, styles bundle.js, and main bundle.js.

At the bottom of my index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
```

The files are in the same folder as index.html, with all of the angular 2 goodies. When I copy the text into the corresponding script tags, it works just fine.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by this: "When I copy the text into the corresponding script tags, it works just fine."

Comment: do you put your app in a folder on your webserver?
then you need to set the base-href when you build "ng build --bh /myUrl/"

Comment: @ppovoski meaning, I copy the text from inline.js, put it in the first script tag, copy styles.bundle.js, put it in the second tag, etc.

Comment: @Johan Blomgren not even at that stage, just trying to pop index.html into a browser. No serving (yet).

Comment: May be a web server issue.  I use a static web server to test built projects locally.  If you can see the files are in the same directory as the index.html file, can you open the inline.js file in a new browser tab?  How is your web server handling *.js files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @Johan Blomgren for the answer. Adding this fixed it:

```
<base href="index.html">
```

Comment: Thank you soo much, saved me a day or two.